# Dynamically create compiler error based on API usage?

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, static-analysis

Did not know how to search for an answer to this, but I am wondering if there is a way in a compiled language such as Java, C#, Scala etc... To force a compiler error where an API is used incorrectly.

Say you have some sort of API you are working with and you know you need to call a specific setup method X before calling some other method Y, is it possible to set things up such that the compiler will catch the error and avoid having to do so at run time?

It would be fairly useful for enforcing some code standards or fixing broken API's. No idea if its even possible though.

Comment: There is very limited things you can do for preprocessing. Most likely only runtime errors can deal with that.

Comment: @AlvinWong: Oh, but there *is* a static feature that can verify some requirements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools like [NDepend (for .NET)](http://www.ndepend.com/) or [JArchitect (for java)](http://www.jarchitect.com/) lets write [custom code rules over LINQ queries](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) that can emit [warning or error](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_CriticalRule.aspx) at analysis time ([in the IDE](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx), or [at Build Process time](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule)). For example the following CQLinq code rule enforces that if a method is calling `MethodA()`, it must call `MethodB()`:

```
warnif count > 0 
from m in Application.Methods where
 m.IsUsing("MyNamespace.MyClass.MyMethodA()") &&
!m.IsUsing("MyNamespace.MyClass.MyMethodB()")
select m
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can't create arbitrary custom compile-time errors in most static languages. There are a few exceptions (like `#error` directives in C and C++, but even then the preprocessor comes strictly before the main compilation so that won't help).

However, you can utilize a language feature specifically designed to catch errors at compile time:

### The type system is your friend.

Requiring methods to be called in a particular order is unfriendly to API consumers, and is a code smell in a high-level language.

A trivial solution is to expose a single method that performs both operations in the correct order. More generally (e.g. if the 2nd method doesn't have to be called), have the 2nd method call the 1st method at the top. But presumably you want the calls to be under the control of the API consumer.

In that case, refactor your code so that it is not possible to call methods in the wrong order without creating a type error. For example, suppose you're writing a regex library where regexes have to be compiled before matching. In Scala, refactor:

```
class Regex(pattern : String) {
    private[this] var compiled : Option[CompiledData] = None
    def compile() {
        // do stuff
        this.compiled = ...
    }
    def search(s : String) : MatchResult = compiled match {
        case Some(c) => ... // match the string
        case None => throw new IllegalStateException("must compile regex first")

    }
}
```

to

```
class Regex(pattern : String) {
    def compile : CompiledRegex = {
        // do stuff
        CompiledRegex(...)
    }
}
class CompiledRegex(c : CompiledData) {
    def search(s : String) : MatchResult = {
        ... // match the string
    }
}
```

Since the `search` method is now only available on `CompiledRegex`, and `CompiledRegex` is obtained by calling `Regex.compile`, it's impossible to call `search` before that action is made valid by compiling the regex.

This setup also helps out API consumers, because if the user needs an object of type `MatchResult` and has already typed `new Regex("[abc123]*")`, a good IDE can autocomplete or suggest the needed method `.compile`; that would not be possible with the original setup.

(In this example, it also no longer needs mutable state, which is often avoided in Scala.)

### Static assertions

As an alternative solution, some languages (I think D and C++11, though not the ones you listed) support static assertions.

Comment: I agree this is the right approach, but sometimes it is not possible without wrappers etc.... Hence I want to have some sort of checking built into the compiler for this.

Answer (score 1):

the usage of specific functions ist on another level than the compiler operation ... therefore i don't think that a compiler should do things like that ...

on the other hand: compilers are commonly integrated into IDEs ... why don't you put that into an IDE module too? ... most IDEs allow pre compiler operations ...

you could write some sort of checking tool (based on CodeDOM or something similar) to test for specific function usage, and based on that check-result, abort the compiler run if the quality criteria is not matched ...